# Mandar mail con ASP .NET en visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, smtp

hola buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente codie para que enviara mails desde mi visual studio 2017, pero el problema que una vez que lo hago correr al programa  y cargo todos lo campos ,  le doy click al boton enviar se queda esperando un rato(tengo que entendido que tarda un rato en enviar un mail) y luego se cierra solo la depuración(deja de correr el programa). Alguna idea? un tengo que configurar algo en mi visual

```
  protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtRemitente.Text, txtContraseña.Text);
        MailMessage msj = new MailMessage();
        msj.From = new MailAddress(txtRemitente.Text);
        msj.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtDestinatario.Text));
        msj.Subject = txtAsunto.Text;
        msj.Body = txtMensaje.Text;
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(msj);
            lblMensaje.Text = "Fue enviado con exito";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lblMensaje.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

frontend

```
Remitente: <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemitente" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<br />
<br />

Contraseña: <asp:TextBox ID="txtContraseña" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>

<br />
<br />

Asunto: <asp:TextBox ID="txtAsunto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<br />
<br />

Destinatario: <asp:TextBox ID="txtDestinatario" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<br />
<br />

Mensaje: <asp:TextBox ID="txtMensaje" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblMensaje" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="btnEnviar" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="btnEnviar_Click" />
```

Comment: Varias cosas. Depurate tu codigo paso a paso para ver donde se queda trabado? Visual Studio es el entorno que usas para desarrollar, no tiene nada que ver con tu codigo. Tu codigo es C#, y las clases son C# y todo lo que haces esta en C#.

Comment: Hice lo que me digiste hice el paso a paso, carga todos los valores pero cuando entra al metodo SEND() espera un rato y se cierra solo. @gbianchi

Comment: No sale ni siquiera por el catch.. eso si que es raro... esperemos a ver si alguien ve algo mas.

Comment: por eso por que si habria algun error (lo veria en la excepcion) o estaria pasando mal los datos lo veria en la depuracion... GRACIAS IGUAL!

Comment: Creo que una buena opción sería aislarlo a una app de consola y así descartar algo de tu ambiente específico. Prueba solo el código que envía el mensaje e intenta enviar un *hola mundo* desde la app de consola usando la misma cuenta que usas acá.